# responsive webdesign: text out of div tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a website and i'm trying to make it responsive.

The problem I have is that the text will not dynamicly adjust to the content size.

maybe you guys can help me?

thanks in advance!

Comment: the best way is to use some responsive framework like http://www.getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Their are a couple ways you can change it, first of all you can use media queries in your css, which says that when your screen is a certain size the font-size will increase or decrease. I prefer to make the div bigger instead though. A bigger or smaller font size is only usefull when you want a smaller title for certain devices.

With the div width just give the div a width in % (100% for example) and make the height auto, now the div will auto size when you make it smaller but all of the text is still visible for everyone. If u want an example you could take a look at my personal website and make the homepage bigger and smaller, its not perfect but its working (www.svbennekom.nl)